# Angular unit testing functions

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have just started exploring unit testing in angular.
I have a function in .ts file

```
onValueChange(val: number): void {
this.formGroup.get(this.controlName).setValue(val);
}
```

I am trying to test if the controlName has the value passed in the onValueChange parameters

I tried this in the spec.ts file

```
it('form value should update from form changes', fakeAsync(() => {
onValueChange(5);
expect(component.formGroup.get(component.controlName)).toEqual(5); 
}));
function onValueChange(val: number): void {
component.formGroup.get(component.controlName).setValue(val);
}
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing same things in your expect statement.

```
expect(component.formGroup.get(component.controlName).value).toEqual(5);
```

You missed '.value'

Apart from this, I don't think what you are doing will count as testing the original onValueChange function in theory. I am not sure why you have the function under test inside a .ts file rather than a .component.ts file.
If your functionality is wrapped in a component, you can easily configure the TestBed and don't need to repeat the functionality in test file.
Alas, if you can't put it inside a component even then I wouldn't recommend recreating the original functionality inside the test file. In such scenarios(ideal solution would be to avoid such scenarios) there are a couple of workarounds.

```
import myTestFunc from 'myFile.ts';
describe('Test function', () => {
    let testObj;
    beforeEach(()=>{
        testObj = {myTestFunc: myTestFunc};
    });
    it('test', ()=>{
        expect(testObj.myTestFunc()).toBe(something);
    });
});
```

Something like this even allows you to use spies.